# Determine actual Kafka version that is being used inside confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.2 image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to determine the exact version of Kafka inside confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.2 image. On this site, https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#cp-and-apache-ak-compatibility I have read that inside image with tag 6.2.x kafka version 2.8.x is being used but I want to determine the exact version of kafka. I want to know whether the exact version is 2.8.1 or 2.8.0. I also went inside this folder inside docker container /usr/share/java/kafka but could not determine the exact version of the kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, version should not matter for clients. Besides, you can always use `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:6.2.2-ccs` as well in Java code, assuming you've added the [Confluent Maven repo](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-kafka-java/current/overview.html).

From the container, I don't think you can find this. Confluent [overrides the version](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/v6.2.2-22-ccs/gradle.properties#L22) in their Kafka repo fork.

Outside of the documentation, you can see in their Jenkinsfile [the mapping between versions](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/v6.2.2-22-ccs/Jenkinsfile#L53), and the [changelog between versions is here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/6.2.2/release-notes/changelog.html).

If you really need a more explicit broker version, I'd suggest [`bitnami/kafka`](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/tags)

Answer (score 0):

The release notes for Confluent Platform 6.2.2 state that it uses Kafka 2.8.0.

See here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/6.2.2/release-notes/index.html